Why doesn't App.exe.config update when using My.Settings.Save() or MySettings.Default.Save()?
I've been chasing my tail and several SO articles around App.exe.config files.  Everything I read stipulates that it indeed should be included with my application, even for a WPF app.
So, when I copy the files to another folder location and attempt to use it, I'm not seeing any update in the App.exe.config file.
Instead, I'm seeing it update in C:\users\username\AppData\Local\AppName_Url_vwndydm5awsw44xgnthq0lonv15jmpyh\#.#.#.#\user.config
Granted, these settings are setup as "User" settings, even though the App.exe.config file has these as original values.
What on earth do I need to do for it to update App.exe.config instead of the AppData file?
Using VB.Net for .Net 3.5.
Sample:
Private Sub DecreaseFont_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Decrease_Font.Click
    MySettings.Default.Reload()
    'My.Settings.Reload()
    Dim currentSize As Integer = My.Settings.Font_Size
    Dim newSize As Integer = currentSize - 2

    If newSize >= 10 Then
      FunLabel.FontSize = newSize
    End If
    MySettings.Default.Font_Size = newSize
    'My.Settings.Font_Size = newSize
    MySettings.Default.Save()
    'My.Settings.Save()
    '    My.Settings.Reload()

End Sub


The exe.config file contains the original value, set in the Designer. When you change the original values, these new values are stored in a user.config file (you could not have a .Settings.Default.Reset() method otherwise). Read the notes here about this

So there's no way to change the user settings stored in ..\AppFolder\App.exe.config instead of creating a folder within C:\Users\user\AppData?

The whole point of the .exe.config file is to preserve values set at design, so, as mentioned, you can reset the settings to default values when needed. The folder in AppData is created automatically; it's also updated when you change the version of your assembly (new folders are added, reflecting the assembly version) -- To mention that, these days, many choose to store their settings in a JSON file (appsettings.json, more specifically, in .NET 6+). Kind of mandatory (not exactly, but...) if you use recent versions of Dependency Injection

Understood.  So really, I need to develop a method which will check the AppData folder for any existing folders and import any previous settings should there be an equivalent setting name / value, and then remove the outdated folder path to keep the folder structure clean for future updates.

You're not really supposed to touch that schema -- This is really old stuff, the folders proliferation is quite annoying, the Upgrade() method, which is meant to synchronize the versions' settings, sometimes makes a mess... it's really old stuff

Yeah . . . unfortunately I'm forced to work within .Net 3.5 . . . blegh

Also be aware that the .exe.config file resides in the application's installation directory, where the application may not even have write permissions.
